# How can I get send AND receive timestamps from tcpdump for packets I send over local loopback?

Tags: tcp, timestamp, localhost, tcpdump

I'm trying to run tests on a simulated network I'm running on my machine and would like to get timing information on packets I'm sending and then receiving over local loopback.

When I run `tcpdump -i lo` I see two packets for every packet of data I send over local loopback: a data-carrying packet with a sequence number, and an associated `ack` packet. Each has only 1 timestamp associated with it.

I'd like to see when the data-carrying packet is sent and received, and when the ack packet is sent and received-- that is, 4 timestamps in total. I can't figure out how to do this in tcpdump no matter what Google searches I try or flags I pass it.

Right now I'm only getting 2 timestamps, one for each packet. I'm pretty sure they are both receive times for the packets.

I could probably run this test using two different machines, but I don't have another one on hand right now, and if I did that the clock between the two wouldn't be synchronized perfectly so the timestamps would be off.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what I'm asking for here is impossible. When sending over local loopback, the kernel uses a purely software layer, so there are no TCP packets actually being sent.

This is actually true for using any device and sending to yourself-- the kernel automatically optimizes and doesn't actually use the hardware to send packets.

In order to get send and receive times, you need to route through some other external agent. Alternatively, you can pretend there are two different interfaces running on your computer using `netns`, then connect them using virtual ethernet (`veth`) and then log `tcpdump` data over that connection.

See [this blog post](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/) on setting up a connected `netns` namespace.